# How can I add a subcategory to axis in Plotly with R?

Tags: r, plotly, categories, axis

I am trying to add a second category to x axis with Plotly under R like this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
library(plotly)

data <- data.frame(day=  c(1:4),
                   visit = c("visit1","visit1", "visit2", "visit2"),
                   val = c(1:4),
                   flag = c("","","", 1))

fig <- plot_ly(data= data, x = ~day) %>%
  
  add_trace(y = ~val,
            type = 'scatter',
            mode = 'lines+markers',
            line = list(width = 2, 
                        dash = 'solid')) %>%
  
  add_trace(data= data %>% filter(flag == 1), y = 0, 
            type = 'scatter', 
            hoverinfo = "text",
            mode = 'markers',
            name = "flag",
            text = paste("<br>N°",data$ID[data$flag == 1], 
                         "<br>Day",data$day[data$flag == 1]),
            marker = list(
              color = 'red',
              symbol = "x",
              size = 12
            ),
            showlegend = T
  )

fig
```

[image: Without Category]

I have tried this, which seems good but the markers disappear from the graph, maybe due to the filter on data.

```
library(plotly)

data <- data.frame(day=  c(1:4),
                   visit = c("visit1","visit1", "visit2", "visit2"),
                   val = c(1:4),
                   flag = c("","","", 1))

fig <- plot_ly(data= data, x = ~list(visit,day)) %>%
  
  add_trace(y = ~val,
            type = 'scatter',
            mode = 'lines+markers',
            line = list(width = 2, 
                        dash = 'solid')) %>%
  
  add_trace(data= data %>% filter(flag == 1), y = 0, 
            type = 'scatter', 
            hoverinfo = "text",
            mode = 'markers',
            name = "flag",
            text = paste("<br>N°",data$ID[data$flag == 1], 
                         "<br>Day",data$day[data$flag == 1]),
            marker = list(
              color = 'red',
              symbol = "x",
              size = 12
            ),
            showlegend = T
  )

fig
```

[image: Category without filter]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide a reproducible question, so I've made data. (Well, data I shamelessly stole from [here](https://plotly.com/python/categorical-axes/)). This creates a bar graph with two sets of x-axis labels. One for each set of bars. One for each group of bars. The content of the x-axis is the same in both traces.

```
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly() %>% 
  add_bars(x = list(rep(c("first", "second"), each = 2),
                    rep(LETTERS[1:2], 2)),
           y = c(2, 5, 2, 6),
           name = "Adults") %>% 
  add_bars(x = list(rep(c("first", "second"), each = 2),
                    rep(LETTERS[1:2], 2)),
           y = c(1, 4, 3, 6),
           name = "Children")
fig
```

[image]

---

---

#### Update

You added data and code trying to apply this to your data. I added an update and apparently missed what the problem was. Sorry about that.

Now that I'm paying attention (let's hope, right?), here is an actual fix to the actual problem.

For this change, I modified your data. Instead of the `flag` annotated with a one, I changed it to zero. Then I used `flag` as a variable.

```
data <- data.frame(day = c(1:4),
                   visit = c("visit1","visit1", "visit2", "visit2"),
                   val = c(1:4),
                   flag = c("","","", 0))

fig <- plot_ly(data= data, x = ~list(visit,day)) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~val,
            type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers',
            line = list(width = 2, 
                        dash = 'solid')) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~flag, 
            type = 'scatter', hoverinfo = "text",
            mode = 'markers', name = "flag",
            text = paste("<br>N°",data$ID[data$flag == 1], 
                         "<br>Day",data$day[data$flag == 1]),
            marker = list(
              color = 'red', symbol = "x", size = 12),
            showlegend = T)
fig
```

You're going to get a warning about discrete & non-discrete data, which isn't really accurate, but it shows up, nonetheless.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Kat for your answer.

Yes you're right. I have modified my previous post to include data for a reproducible example. With "x=list", when a filter is applied on the second trace, the category is well displayed but the second trace disappears from the graphic.

Comment: The reason it didn't work is that you used numbers as numbers. Check out my update.

Comment: Thank you Kat. I've tried with your update but the marker still does not appear :(

Comment: Wow, I am sorry. I completely missed the mark on that update. I've updated my answer, again. This fixes the problem you're actually having. (sigh)

Comment: My comment skipped Oo ==> "It works ! Thank you Kat !!!"